# Push notification - Different badge numbers for different users

Tags: ios, ios4, push-notification

In my app the users can login and see a list of all members. They can also chat with each of the users in a private chat.

When one of the users has left the chat the server notifies the user that he has received a new chat message.

But it's the same property (applicationBadgeNumber) that gets updated all the time.

I wan't to accomplish something like this when you login and see the member list:

**Member list:**

- Peter
- Adam (**3** new messages)
- Anders
- Niklas (**1** new message)

I don't know what to call this but unique push notifications for certain users.

The "Wordfeud" app does exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot increment or decrement badge number using push-notifications. You can only set **NEW** `value`!

You can know current badge value only if your application is now running.

If you extremely want to add such feature you should store current user's badge value at your server and send appropriate value with your push-notification.

P.S. It's very strange that Apple didn't think about it when they were developing badge numbers and push-notifications. =(

Comment: I understand that you can't increment or decrement badge number. My question is if you in theory can support different badge numbers (in lack of a better phrase) for different users: I have 2 new messages from usernameBadgeNumber, I have 6 new messages from username2BadgeNumber. The Wordfeud app does this, I wonder how...

Comment: I'm sure Apple has thought of it. The APNS API is pretty small, and it  doesn't have any state, so it makes sense that you're responsible for handling the state yourself.